# Insert UTF-8 characters to CartoDB database

Tags: jquery, sql, utf-8, cartodb

I'm using Cartodb.js and API to insert strings from jquery variables to my dataset table in Cartodb.

```
//Store variable
data.location = $('#location').val();

//Insert to SQL
var SQL = 'INSERT INTO {{tablename}} (location) VALUES (\'{{location}}\');'
```

When a string contains special characters (æ,ø,å) they are stored in Cartodb as �.

Is there a way to get this to work? All files are stored with UTF-8 encoding. Could I pass some commands to my SQL command to have the values stored in UTF-8?